# Refactoring Laravel isset params to eloquent when condition

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to clean up my code, so i have decided to start using the `when` option instead of isset in my querys ... But it doesnt seem to be working and I cant see where I am going wrong.

My original code looks like so;

```php
$params['game'] = 'fallout';

$gameQuery = Gaming::query();

$gameSelect = isset($params['game']) ? $params['game'] : null;
if ($gameSelect) {
    $gameQuery = $gameQuery->where('game' $gameSelect);
}
```

This has been working in the codebase now for a number of years.

I tried refactoring to the following, using the `when` keyword

```php
$params['game'] = 'fallout';

$gameQuery = Gaming::query();

$gameQuery->when($params['game'], function ($query) use ($params) {
    $query->where('game', $params['game']);
});
```

But for some reason it just skips over there where statement.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: try dumping sql query to check if it is skipped or not `dd($gameQuery->toSql())`

Comment: @MilanTarami Yes thats what I did, and it does skip it

Comment: dd($params['game']); before when callback ,what you get it

Comment: try $gameQuery->when(isset($params['game']), function ($query) use ($params) {
    $query->where('game', $params['game']);
});

Comment: Chain it `Gaming::when($params['game'], function ($query) use ($params) {
    $query->where('game', $params['game']);
});` or reasign it to your variable `$gameQuery = $gameQuery->when($params['game'], function ($query) use ($params) {
    $query->where('game', $params['game']);
});`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$gameQuery->when(isset($params['game']) 
, function ($query) use ($params) {
     $query->where('game', $params['game']);
 });
```